# Predicting missing values with scikit-learn's Imputer module

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, prediction, imputation

I am writing a very basic program to predict missing values in a dataset using **scikit-learn's Imputer** class.

I have made a NumPy array, created an Imputer object with strategy='mean' and performed fit_transform() on the NumPy array.

When I print the array after performing fit_transform(), the 'Nan's remain, and I dont get any prediction.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I go about predicting the missing values?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

X = np.array([[23.56],[53.45],['NaN'],[44.44],[77.78],['NaN'],[234.44],[11.33],[79.87]])

print X

imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imp.fit_transform(X)

print X
```

Comment: That's not generally called prediction, it's called imputation. Unless the missing values are all in the future.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.fit_transform), `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.fit_transform` returns *a new array*, it doesn't alter the argument array. The minimal fix is therefore:

```
X = imp.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: That is working fine, thanks.

However, the predicted values for all missing values are coming out to be the same. I took much larger datasets too and still all 'NaN's were being replaced by the same value. What do I need to change in my program?

Comment: These aren't "predicted" values, they're just replacements for missing data. Your strategy is `'mean'`, so it will *"replace missing values using the mean along the axis"*.

Comment: Okay. Which algorithm should I use for predicting the missing values then?

Comment: I don't know - you haven't said how you want them to be replaced. Also, I'm basically just reading the documentation to answer your questions - why don't you have a look there?

Comment: Additionally, you can set `copy=False` in the constructor to do imputation in-place and avoid creating a copy whenever possible.

Comment: @Rayu You may want to use multiple imputation to do this correctly.  See here for more information about doing so using pandas and the very nice port of MICE by Frank Cheng: http://gsocfrankcheng.blogspot.ca/

Answer (score 8):

After **scikit-learn version 0.20** the usage of impute module was changed. Now, we can use imputer like;

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
impute = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
impute.fit(X)
X=impute.transform(X)
```

Pay attention:

Instead of **'NaN'**, **np.nan** is used

Don't need to use **axis** parameter

We can use **imp** or **imputer** instead of my `impute` variable

Answer (score 2):

Note: Due to the change in the sklearn library 'NaN' has to be replaced with np.nan as shown below.

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
 imputer = Imputer(missing_values= np.nan,strategy='mean',axis=0)  
 imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
 X[:,1:3]= imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```