# SMOTE with missing values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am trying to use SMOTE from `imblearn` package in Python, but my data has a lot of missing values and I got the following error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

I checked the parameters [here](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html), and it seems that there is not one dealing with missing value.

Is there a way to generate synthetic samples with missing values?

Answer (score 5):

SMOTE does not perform filling up your missing or NaN values. You need to fill them up and then feed for SMOTE analysis. Dealing with missing values is a different task altogether, you can take a look at [Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) from sklearn to begin with. Here is another write-up on sklearn regarding missing values : [Imputing missing values](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/impute.html)

Once you have finished dealing with NaN values, then feed your modified data to `SMOTE`.

References

- [Predicting missing values with Scikit-learn Imputer module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017626/predicting-missing-values-with-scikit-learns-imputer-module)
- [Handling missing data with Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/)
- [Handling missing values](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/handling-missing-values)

Comment: Xgboost and lighgbm fitting data with missing values, thus I thought it's possible that generate some synthetic data even when there is missing value. Maybe not SMOTE, but I intuitively thought there might be some way. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

A simple example is the following:

```
# Imports
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

# Load data
bc = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = bc.data, bc.target

# Initial number of samples per class
print('Number of samples for both classes: {} and {}.'.format(*Counter(y).values()))

# SMOTEd class distribution
print('Dataset has %s missing values.' % np.isnan(X).sum())
_, y_resampled = SMOTE().fit_sample(X, y)
print('Number of samples for both classes: {} and {}.'.format(*Counter(y_resampled).values()))

# Generate artificial missing values
X[X > 1.0] = np.nan
print('Dataset has %s missing values.' % np.isnan(X).sum())
_, y_resampled = make_pipeline(Imputer(), SMOTE()).fit_sample(X, y)
print('Number of samples for both classes: {} and {}.'.format(*Counter(y_resampled).values()))
```

Comment: Looks like SMOTE cannot handle NaNs.    ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').